# Does unpacking enums at the global scope increase memory usage?

Tags: python, enums

I have a module that contains a little over of 500 lines of `Enum` definitions, to be clear it's not just single 500 line enum, but several `Enums`. Please correct me if I misunderstand, by unpacking the `Enum` I am only creating a reference?

```py
# app/enums.py
import enum


class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3


A, B, C = MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C
```

Comment: It creates 3 new variables, they use memory.

Comment: Yes, you're only creating references. Why would this be different from any other variable assignments?

Comment: Python assignments never make copies. You have to do that explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar, instead of several comments, please write one answer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use any more memory than any other variable assignments. Assignments always just create references, which are generally just pointers internally; you need to perform an explicit copy operation to duplicate the data.

```
l = [[1], [2], [3]]
A, B, C = l # references to the nested lists
X, Y, Z = (x.copy() for x in l) # copies of the nested lists
```

Comment: You might note though that references take memory too!  The size of a pointer, at least in CPython.

Comment: That's what I tried to suggest "no more than any other variable assignment". The OP seems to be concerned that it will use more memory than just a reference.

Comment: I've improved the example so it's structured data that might conceivably be copied.